# Empty object matches object with different properties on toMatchObject in Jest

Tags: testing, jestjs, match

When testing a object with properties with an empty object, my test **PASSES**:

```js
it('Should not match object with properties with empty object', () => {
  const testingObject = { a: 1, b: 2 };

  expect(testingObject).toMatchObject({});
});
```

Now, when comparing with object that has another property that is not part of the `testingObject` my test **PASSES**, which is expected:

```js
it('Should not match object with property that does not exist in the original object', () => {
  const testingObject = { a: 1, b: 2 };

  expect(testingObject).not.toMatchObject({ c: 3 });
});
```

This behaviour is strange as i would expect first test to fail because `{}` does not have `a` and `b` properties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that this is an expected behaviour per this [Jest Github issue](https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/8308).

Also one of the contributors added an [explanation](https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/8308#issuecomment-483785775):

> non-empty received object like {hello: 'hello'} does match empty expected object
>
> empty received object does not match non-empty expected object like {hello: 'hello'}
>
> That is, received value must have all the expected properties, but can have additional properties.

This means that we should expect for this to happen for expected empty object is at least an object same as received object, but cannot have properties that are not part of the received object.

---

**SOLUTION:**
 (EDIT from comment:)
There is an option for [checking a property existence](https://jestjs.io/docs/expect#tohavepropertykeypath-value), and also to check value along with that property check.

```js
it('Should not match object with properties with empty object', () => {
  const testingObject = { a: 1, b: 2 };

  expect(testingObject).toHaveProperty('a', 1);
  expect(testingObject).toHaveProperty('b', 2);
});
```

This solution is a bit explicit and it does not solve the original problem with equality of empty object.

Comment: If all you want to know is that those properties exist, you can use https://jestjs.io/docs/expect#tohavepropertykeypath-value (but generally you should be able to be more specific about your expectations).

Comment: Ah cool, i'll edit my answer, good find. Thanks